# How to embed tweets in umbraco / articulate articles?

Tags: twitter, umbraco, umbraco7

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nc-BbPaEXtI) video is showing how to embed tweets in umbraco 7. In the current version it does not seem to work anymore. When I try to do it I get the error message "not supported".

[image]

Is there anything additionally to do to get this working? Any additional packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that feature uses OEMBED, it's possible that Twitter have updated their API and the functionality is broken. I'd log an issue on the Umbraco Issue logger: http://issues.umbraco.org so that the core dev are aware of the issue and can investigate further.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have created an issue here: http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-8568

Answer (score 0):

Could also try this package https://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/utwit/ , have used it before and works perfect but haven't tried it on v7 yet but it says it work and i trust Matt (the guy that made it big umbraco dev and contributor) so should work.

Comment: uTwit's purpose is to embed Twitter elements on the page but isn't to embed tweets in articles, is it?